# How to pull data from Instagram API without submitting for review

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm creating a social media feed for my website that requires pulling image urls, description text, like count, hashtags, etc. I have created an instagram developer account but whenever I try and run the code to obtain a user id i get a blank response:

```
    <?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=$user_name&client_id=$client_id&access_token=$access_token");
var_dump($json);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data);
```

Response:

```
    array (size=2)
  'data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'meta' => 
    array (size=1)
      'code' => int 200
```

My client is still in sandbox mode if that makes any difference.

I'm trying to get the user id of a username that is not the same as the developer account i'm using so i can get the information i need to create my feed. The commands I am trying to use are:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$userId/media/recent/?access_token=$token
```

EDIT: Fixed the code above, the command can also be pasted in the URL bar

Comment: Please elaborate on the code or provide more code. If the response is 200, then maybe the set of query parameters doesn't return any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now a days Instagram stopped giving permission to access other than basic profile , so don't waste your time , you will no get permission out of sandbox for release.